# Code must be in VBSCRIPT or Shell Script

Tags: shell, vbscript

Hi I need to read from a text file and copy files whose name are present in that file. location of the files are different and i need to copy it from one location to another

```vbs
Const DestinationFile = "C:\Users\$svijay8\Desktop\libnew\"
Const SourceFile = "C:\Users\$svijay8\Desktop\lib\*"
Dim fso
Dim fName
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(DestinationFile) Then
  WScript.Echo "Folder is there"
Else
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set listFile = fso.OpenTextFile("inputold.txt")
  do while not listFile.AtEndOfStream
    fName =  listFile.ReadLine()
    Set fName = fso.GetFile(C:\Users\$svijay8\Desktop\lib\*so)
    If fname.FileExists("C:\Users\$svijay8\Desktop\lib\*") Then
      WScript.Echo "Reached If loop in do while in If condition above copy"
      fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\Users\$svijay8\Desktop\libnew\", True
    Else
    End If
  loop
End If
```

Comment: Please click "Edit" and add 4 spaces to the start of each line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "Code must be in VBScript or ??shell??". Do you mean Powershell? or MS-DOS BATCH commands for CMD.EXE? Or have you installed a proper Unix-like shell (e.g. bash) on your Windows box?

Anyway, you should be able to do it like this - if you call this "shell".

```
For /f %%f in (inputold.txt) do copy /y c:\source\%%f c:\dest
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response but it should be in either shell scripting or VB scripting

Comment: What do you mean by "shell"? Powershell?